# are there any drawbacks resulting from using BIGINT column type with AUTOINCRETEMENT in MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I would like to have an autoincrement primary key, which is very far to reach its limit.
Therefore, I want to use BIGINT type.
but I wonder "are there any drawbacks resulting from using BIGINT column type with AUTOINCRETEMENT in MySQL table?"
Thanks

Comment: I don't see any problem with that.

Comment: There exists special alias `SERIAL` == `BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE`... none another datatype has similar alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem to do that.
Actually I have multiple tables on prod using BIGINT as autoincremented id.

And you must do it if you think your index will grow up to more then  2147483647 for INT(11) :

```
TINYINT = 1 byte (8 bit)
SMALLINT = 2 bytes (16 bit)
MEDIUMINT = 3 bytes (24 bit)
INT = 4 bytes (32 bit)
BIGINT = 8 bytes (64 bit).
```